# How to passing enum in typedef as a float?

Tags: enums, graphql, typedef

I am trying to add float values in enum typedef as given below:

```
enum PRIORITYTYPE {
        0.1
        0.2
        0.3
        0.4
        0.5
        0.6
        0.7
        0.8
        0.9
        1.0
    }
```

But I getting error. How to solve this issue by checking fixed values and place it in typedef? whereas string working proper when I enter sting as given but not float nor int

```
enum FREQUENCYTYPE {
        Daily
        Weekly
        Monthly
        Yearly
    }
```

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: It's graphql for typedef enum default array values input.